# How to perform search on data that is stored in context api in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i am doing one task in that i have json data and I am using context api to pass data in different component. but i am facing problem in how to perform search operation when user enter something input field in search box, how can i get filtered data from context api ?

Comment: It's better to include some code of Context and Consumers

Comment: Do you want to do server side filtering?

Answer (score 0):

A big problem with making request based on user input is that you don't know in what order they resolve. If a user types `a` and then another `a` the app would make a request with `a` and then `aa`. If the first request takes 5 seconds and the second request takes 1 second then the search result of `aa` comes in first and the ui is set with this result. Then the result of `a` would come in and the ui will be set with that result. Problem now is that the user typed `aa` but result for `a` is showing.

See the hidden snippet below where if you type `aa` quickly then the result for `a` comes in after `aa` and those results will be shown:

```js
const data = ['aa', 'ab', 'bb'];
const later = (value, time) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), time)
  );
const getData = (query) =>
  later(
    data.filter((d) => d.includes(query)),
    query.length === 1 ? 500 : 100
  );
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: true,
    filter: '',
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState((s) => ({ ...s, loading: true }));
    getData(state.filter).then(
      (data) =>
        console.log(
          'setting result based on filter:',
          state.filter
        ) ||
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, data, loading: false }))
    );
  }, [state.filter]);
  const changeFilter = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const filter = e.target.value;
    setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      filter,
    }));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={changeFilter} />
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

It logs the following:

```
setting result based on filter: 
setting result based on filter: aa
setting result based on filter: a
```

First log is when the component mounted and search is empty, second is when you typed `aa` and the search resolved and the third is when you typed `a` (need to type `a` before you can type `aa`) and the search resolved. Now the UI ends up showing results for `a` but UI showing you are searching for `a`

What you want to do is only resolve the api promise (and set the UI) when it was the last request, see snippet below:

```js
const data = ['aa', 'ab', 'bb'];
const later = (value, time) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), time)
  );
const REPLACED = 'REPLACED';
const last = (fn) => {
  const current = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const latest = {};
    current.latest = latest;
    return Promise.resolve(fn(...args)).then((resolve) =>
      current.latest === latest
        ? resolve
        : Promise.reject(REPLACED)
    );
  };
};
const getData = last((query) =>
  later(
    data.filter((d) => d.includes(query)),
    query.length === 1 ? 500 : 100
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: true,
    filter: '',
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState((s) => ({ ...s, loading: true }));
    getData(state.filter).then(
      (data) =>
        console.log(
          'setting result based on filter:',
          state.filter
        ) ||
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, data, loading: false })),
      (error) =>
        console.log(
          `error: ${error} for filter: ${state.filter}`
        )
    );
  }, [state.filter]);
  const changeFilter = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const filter = e.target.value;
    setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      filter,
    }));
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={changeFilter} />
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Now it will log:

```
setting result based on filter: 
setting result based on filter: aa
error: REPLACED for filter: a
```

Almost the same as the first snippet but instead of the slow request resolving it is now rejecting with the error REPLACED. This is because when search for `a` comes in it was already replaced with a newer request for `aa`.

Here is a full example with the fake api call `getData` in React.Context

```js
const data = ['aa', 'ab', 'bb'];
const later = (value, time) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), time)
  );
const REPLACED = 'REPLACED';
const last = (fn) => {
  const current = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const latest = {};
    current.latest = latest;
    return Promise.resolve(fn(...args)).then((resolve) =>
      current.latest === latest
        ? resolve
        : Promise.reject(REPLACED)
    );
  };
};
const getData = last((query) =>
  later(
    data.filter((d) => d.includes(query)),
    query.length === 1 ? 500 : 100
  )
);

const Data = React.createContext();
const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: true,
    filter: '',
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState((s) => ({ ...s, loading: true }));
    getData(state.filter).then(
      (data) =>
        console.log(
          'setting result based on filter:',
          state.filter
        ) ||
        setState((s) => ({ ...s, data, loading: false })),
      (error) =>
        console.log(
          `error: ${error} for filter: ${state.filter}`
        )
    );
  }, [state.filter]);
  const changeFilter = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const filter = e.target.value;
    setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      filter,
    }));
  }, []);
  return (
    <Data.Provider value={{ state, changeFilter }}>
      {children}
    </Data.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { state, changeFilter } = React.useContext(Data);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={changeFilter} />
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <DataProvider>
    <App />
  </DataProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until the user is done typing, look into debouncing https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

If you want to kill in-flight requests when the user types something new before the first request comes back, look into attaching an [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) to each request, and calling the abort method before each new request.